# Fix Angular2 CORS redirects with Zone

Tags: angular, cors, angular2-http, zonejs

I was connecting my app with a REST API in which some operations return response redirects. So I got the error: "Redirects form [url] has been blocked by CORS policy. Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect."

Is it possible to create a new zone (besides angular zone and default zone), catch the error and execute the request manually?

Or... any good idea? The server sometimes return redirect responses.

**UPDATE:**

Flow:

1. I request the url /foo.
2. CORS send a OPTIONS request to /foo
3. When step 2 return ok, then send GET to /foo
4. The server returns a redirect to /bar

The current flow is:

5. The browser throws an exception

The flow I want to get:

5. Catch the exception with zone
6. Read the url to redirect and launch another GET request to /bar

I think using Zone is possible catch the browser exception. The question is HOW?

I'm not sure if I launch an http request out of angular zone and if everything can become unstable.
Do you think this could be possible to do?

Comment: Cors requests are made by the browser without Angular. Can't you fix the server?

Comment: this has nothing to do with Angular. CORS preflight requests are made by browser. Can you elaborate more on your problem.

Comment: Redirects are approved by REST community, so how can I deal with CORS and redirect?

Comment: Why do you think zone is related?

Comment: Because Zone can handle exceptions of async operations. try/catch cannot be used

Comment: Zone can only catch what runs inside it's zone. There is no way at all to catch CORS exceptions.

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks

Comment: I thought if I run the XMLHttpRequest object in a new zone, I would catch errors using zone.